# "To use WhatsApp on your computer, open WhatsApp on your phone"?

Tags: desktop-computer, whatsapp

So, I want to use WhatsApp on my computer. The first step to do that is to... "open WhatsApp on my phone"? Huh? The whole point is to use a computer. Not "phone". I have no "phone". That's why I want to use WhatsApp on my *computer*!

This isn't the first time I've seen this nonsense. Apparently, I can't do anything anymore using an actual computer. If I already had this "WhatsApp" on my "phone", why would I be looking at a page for running it on my computer?

[image]

Comment: Yep, that's a deliberate design from whatsapp, they want the phone as primary tool. It allows you to use whatsapp while working on your computer without having to get your phone out of your pocket for instance.

Comment: Telegram app on the contrary do allow a full web interface (though you still need a phone number to create your account)

Answer (score 0):

Whatsapp is a phone app.  Your identity is linked to your phone number.

Think of the PC app as a kind of remote view for the app - it can't be run on the PC without having a valid login, which is provided from the phone app.

Answer (score 0):

> If I already had this "WhatsApp" on my "phone", why would I be looking at a page for running it on my computer?

Because it has a larger screen, more comfortable keyboard and you may not have your phone around at the moment (but you've paired it in the past).

The web version of Whatsapp is just a client for Whatsapp running on a phone. Whatsapp uses phone numbers to identify (and authorize) users, so it wouldn't really work without a phone.

Comment: telegram does the same, but do allow full app use on computer without phone enabled. Still, they are identifiying you with teh phone number (account creation)